# The engine mode serverless you requested is currently unavailable with 5.7 (2.07.1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

Trying to create an RDS aurora server less with MySQL 2.07.1
and got an error **"The engine mode serverless you requested is currently unavailable. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: xxxx; Proxy: null)"**

Any suggestions would help me a lot

here is the sample code

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",


  "Description" : "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template AuroraServerlessDBCluster: Sample template showing how to create an Amazon Aurora Serverless DB cluster. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon Aurora DB cluster. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",


  "Parameters" : {
      "DBUsername" : {
        "NoEcho" : "true",
        "Description" : "Username for MySQL database access",

        "Type" : "String",
        "MinLength" : "1",
        "MaxLength" : "16",
        "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
        "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
      },
      "DBPassword" : {
        "NoEcho" : "true",
        "Description" : "Password MySQL database access",

        "Type" : "String",
        "MinLength" : "8",

        "MaxLength" : "41",
        "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z0-9]*",
        "ConstraintDescription" : "must contain only alphanumeric characters."
      }
  },

  "Resources" : {
      "RDSCluster" : {
          "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
          "Properties" : {
              "MasterUsername" : {
                  "Ref": "DBUsername"
              },
              "MasterUserPassword" : {
                  "Ref": "DBPassword"
              },
              "DBClusterIdentifier" : "my-serverless-cluster",
              "Engine" : "aurora",
              "EngineVersion" : "2.07.1",
              "EngineMode" : "serverless",
              "ScalingConfiguration" : {
                  "AutoPause" : true,
                  "MinCapacity" : 4,
                  "MaxCapacity" : 32,
                  "SecondsUntilAutoPause" : 1000
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To see which versions are available in `serverless` mode, run this:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine aurora-mysql --filters Name=engine-mode,Values=serverless
```

And if you want to understand which DB versions are available according to the engine mode, just remove the filter:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine aurora-mysql
```

This way you will see what is possible in `serverless` or `provisioned` mode, and the supported DB versions for each.

Especially the `SupportedEngineModes` blocks which generally look like:

```
"SupportedEngineModes": [
   "serverless"
]
```

Or

```
"SupportedEngineModes": [
   "provisioned"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create RDS aurora serverless with Aurora MySQL 2.07.1 which is MySQL 5.7 version[+] [a link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.Versions.html).
Looking into the above code and template parameters, I can see that the "Engine" parameter you have is "aurora" and it should be "aurora-mysql"  for the MySQL 5.7 version [+] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-engine).

Answer (score 0):

I think I used the same [example from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#aws-resource-rds-dbcluster--examples), I made the same mistake when trying to use MySQL 5.7 instead of 5.6 from the example, and inevitably ran into the same issue.

The solution was to set:

```json
    "Engine": "aurora-mysql",
    "EngineVersion": "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1"
```

## How did I figure that out?

From further up in the same doc:

> Engine
>
> The name of the database engine to be used for this DB cluster.
>
> Valid Values: aurora (for MySQL 5.6-compatible Aurora), aurora-mysql (for MySQL 5.7-compatible Aurora), and aurora-postgresql

Also from the same doc:

> EngineVersion
>
> The version number of the database engine to use.
>
> ...
>
> To list all of the available engine versions for aurora-mysql (for MySQL 5.7-compatible Aurora), use the following command:
>
> ```
> aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine aurora-mysql --query "DBEngineVersions[].EngineVersion"
> ```

Running that command using the AWS CLI yields something like:

```
[
    ...
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.06.0",
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.0",
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1",
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1",
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2",
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.3",
    ...
]
```

This lead me to believe the we needed to use the [full Aurora MySQL version number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.Versions.html).